# Internet not working in browser on dual boot mac book pro using reFIT

Tags: networking, dual-boot, firefox, mac, proxy

Recently I installed ubuntu 16.04 on my mac as dual boot using **reFIT**.
I can install packages and can ping to different url successfully , But not able to brows the same url in browser(chromium,firefox). (I can brows internet using tor browser)

Initially it seemed that its a proxy server issue and I disabled proxy system wide using `unset http_proxy` and also I set proxy to `none` in my firefox browser. But still internet is not working.

It is also set to `none` in GUI network option. But still not able to get it work.

Can anyone help me in debugging and solving this issue?

[image][image]